# KMM: casting Kotlin's MutableMap to Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform, mutablemap

I was able to retrieve a **binding Swift Array** from a **Kotlin MutableList** source,
but I can’t find the way to retrieve a **binding Swift Array** from a **Kotlin MutableMap of MutableLists** source, given the map key.

=====

**Kotlin MutableList to binding Swift Array**

*Kotlin MutableList* definition:

```
var path : MutableList<ScreenIdentifier> = mutableListOf()
```

retrieving *Binding Swift Array* => **SUCCESSFUL!**

```
extension Binding where Value == NSMutableArray {
    public func cast() -> Binding<[ScreenIdentifier]> {
        return Binding<[ScreenIdentifier]>(
            get:{ self.wrappedValue as NSArray as! [ScreenIdentifier] },
            set: { self.wrappedValue = NSMutableArray(array: $0) }
        )
    }
}
===
NavigationStack(path: $path.cast()) {
...
}
===
```

=====

**Kotlin MutableMap of MutableList to binding Swift Array**

*Kotlin MutableMap of MutableLists* definition:

```
var paths : MutableMap<String, MutableList<ScreenIdentifier>> = mutableMapOf()
```

retrieving *Binding Swift Array* => **NOT WORKING**

```
extension Binding where Value == NSMutableDictionary {
    public func getPath(level1URI: String) -> Binding<[ScreenIdentifier]> {
        return Binding<[ScreenIdentifier]>(
            get:{
                let dict = self.wrappedValue as NSDictionary as! [String:[ScreenIdentifier]]
                return dict[level1URI] as! NSMutableArray as NSArray as! [ScreenIdentifier]
            },
            set: {
                var modifiedDict = self.wrappedValue as! [NSString:NSMutableArray]
                modifiedDict[level1URI as NSString] = NSMutableArray(array: $0)
                self.wrappedValue = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: modifiedDict as! KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString,NSMutableArray>)
            }
        )
    }
}
===
NavigationStack(path: $paths.getPath(level1URI: myString)) {
...
}
===
```

this is the error given by *XCode*:

> Referencing instance method 'getPath(level1URI:)' on 'Binding'
> requires the types 'KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSMutableArray>'
> and 'NSMutableDictionary' be equivalent

Answer (score -1):

I found it!!!

On the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#collections), it's explained that Kotlin's `MutableMap` cannot cast directly to `NSMutableDictionary`, unlike `MutableList` which can instead cast directly to `NSMutableArray`.

So, the solution is to ignore `NSMutableDictionary` and to deal directly with `KotlinMutableDictionary`.

Here is the correct extension code:

```
extension Binding where Value == KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString,NSMutableArray> {
  public func getPath(level1URI: String) -> Binding<[ScreenIdentifier]> {
    return Binding<[ScreenIdentifier]>(
      get:{
        let dict = self.wrappedValue as! [String:[ScreenIdentifier]]
        return dict[level1URI]!
      },
      set: {
        var modifiedDict = self.wrappedValue as! [NSString:NSMutableArray]
        modifiedDict[level1URI as NSString] = NSMutableArray(array: $0)
        self.wrappedValue = KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSMutableArray>.init(dictionary: modifiedDict)
      }
    )
  }
}
```